# A regex_match is not working as expected

Tags: c++, regex

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    string test = "COPY" ;
    regex r1 = regex ("(COPY\b)(.*)") ; 
    if (regex_match (test,r1) ) {
        cout << "match !!" ;
    } else {
        cout << "not match !!";
    }
```

Ok , I thought that this code print me "match !!" , and that is what I wanted.
But , it give me a "not match !!"
What should I do ?

**notice:**
I want "COPY" to match, but not "COPYs" or "COPYYY", because of it I used "\b" in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double-escape your `\b` because the `\` character is the "escape" sequence in C/C++, like when putting a newline, you use `\n` even though that's ONE character, not two.  So your expression goes from this: `"(COPY\b)(.*)"` to this: `"(COPY\\b)(.*)"`.

For the extreme case, if you want to match a `\` character in a regex, you need this: `"\\\\"` because the `\` character is also the escape character, thus you're escaping the escape.

FYI this is why in .NET they often use their raw string syntax for regular expressions, then you don't need to escape it.  Some other languages don't have this as the escape character, and so regex is easier.

Comment: AFAIK in `C++`, `\b` is a word boundary... And we are discussing `C++` here; And the word boundary is exactly what he wants.

Comment: @OfirFarchy: No, you are confusing `\b` word boundary in regex syntax and `\b` escape sequence in string (this escape sequence is the same in C or C++). You are providing a string to `regex` constructor, so you need to escape ``\`` so that the regex constructor receives `\b` instead of backspace character.

Comment: In C++ the character `'\b'` is a backspace. In regular expressions, the string `"\\b"` (or R"\b" if you have C++11) is a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, fix your brackets (with the `if` statement).

Secondly try:

```
regex r1 = regex ("(COPY)(\\b|$)") ;
```

This will look for '*COPY*' followed either by a word break or at the end of the string.

Meaning your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex>

using namespace std ;

int main () {

    string test = "COPY" ;
    regex r1 = regex ("(COPY)(\\b|$)") ; 
    if (regex_match (test,r1) ) {
        cout << "match !!" ;
    } else {
        cout << "not match !!";
    }
}
```